# javascript function call timing. The best way of implementing this

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have The following in my main javascript file:

```
window.onbeforeunload = function () {
    firstFunction();
}

$("a").live("click", function() {
   secondFunction();
}
```

When user clicks on any link that unloads the page (i.e. navigate to another page), both of those functions get called; FirstFunction() gets called first, then secondFunction() gets called. I want the secondFunction() to get called before the firstFunction();

I was able to achieve this by doing this: setTimeout('firstFunction(),100), but I am wondering if there is a better way of doing this?

Thanks.

Comment: `.live()` is out `.on()` is in. http://api.jquery.com/on/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest you to use mousedown event instead of click.

Answer (score 0):

Try this - give all external links a class="external"

```
window.onbeforeunload = function () {
    firstFunction();
}
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("a").click(function() {
     if ($(this).hasClass("external")) secondFunction();
  });
});
```